# Cannot sign blackberry BAR file generated from apk

Tags: android, blackberry

I'm trying to sign the BAR file generated from apk file but i got this error:

Error: Code signing request failed because it could not be logged. Package-Version-Id [gYACgLU-GLg8YtNMuWU17-BoxsM], Application-Version-Id [gYAEgM4XsG9ppojbj3zOO9gg-Nc], Client-Id [2189468].

I tried to redownlowd the CSK file but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blackberry Development team solved it, it was because of the application name length. there is a limit in the number of characters that can be used for an application name.
link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Cannot-sign-BAR-file-quot-Error-Code-signing-request-failed/m-p/3126695#M7410